# Poker Rank Probabilities in three cards poker game -- single deck vs. multiple decks.

Tags: poker

Poker is a game that plays with a single deck of cards.  However, for the purpose of learning, I want to know the probability of poker hands in multiple decks.  To simplify the problem, let's take a popular three-card poker game, and calculate probabilities of a pair and three-of-a-kind ranks for a single deck, and 8 decks.

Quasi answered my question and provided formulas for a pair and a three-of-a-kind probabilities.  I then followed Quasi's approach, and calculated 3-card, single deck combinations for other ranks (see below). But when I applied an 8 deck factor to the single deck equations the results doesn't look right. Are the equations below correct for single deck, and what modifications are needed for 8-deck?

royal flush equation: COMBIN(4,1)

straight flush equation: COMBIN(12,1)*COMBIN(4,1) - COMBIN(4,1)

straight equation: COMBIN(12,1) * (4 ^ 3 - 4)

flush equation  : COMBIN(4,1)*(COMBIN(13,3) - 12)

Comment: You might just compute the probabilities assuming you draw with replacement, which corresponds to infinite decks.  The only change comes because you deplete the useful cards, which is a larger effect with fewer decks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $k$ standard decks.

**Probability of a pair:**
$$\large{\frac
{
\binom{13}{1}\binom{4k}{2}\binom{48k}{1}
}
{
\binom{52k}{3}
}}
$$
Explanation:

- Choose the rank for the pair: $\binom{13}{1}$ choices.

  Choose the two cards for that rank: $\binom{4k}{2}$ choices.

  Choose the non-pair card: $\binom{48k}{1}$ choices.

**Probability of three-of-a-kind:**
$$\large{\frac
{
\binom{13}{1}\binom{4k}{3}
}
{
\binom{52k}{3}
}}
$$
Explanation:

- Choose the rank for the triple: $\binom{13}{1}$ choices.

  Choose the cards for that rank: $\binom{4k}{3}$ choices.

**Update:**

Answering the additional questions in the OP's edit . . .

**Probability of a royal flush:**
$$\large{\frac
{\binom{4}{1}\binom{k}{1}^3}
{\binom{52k}{3}}
}
$$
Explanation:

- Choose the suit: $\binom{4}{1}$ choices.

  Choose the cards for that suit: $\binom{k}{1}^3$ choices.

**Probability of a straight flush (but not royal):**
$$\large{\frac
{\binom{4}{1}\binom{11}{1}\binom{k}{1}^3}
{\binom{52k}{3}}
}
$$
Explanation:

- Choose the suit: $\binom{4}{1}$ choices.

  Choose the rank for the high card: $\binom{11}{1}$ choices.

  Choose $3$ cards, one for each rank: $\binom{k}{1}^3$ choices.

**Probability of a straight (but not a flush):**
$$\large
{
\frac
{\binom{12}{1}\left(\binom{4k}{1}^3-\binom{4}{1}\binom{k}{1}^3\right)}
{\binom{52k}{3}}
}
$$
Explanation:

- Choose the rank for the high card: $\binom{12}{1}$ choices.

  Choose $3$ cards, one for each rank: $\binom{4k}{1}^3$ choices.

  Subtract the count for the flushes:  $\binom{4}{1}\binom{k}{1}^3$ choices.

**Probability of a flush (but not a straight):**
$$\large
{
\frac
{\binom{4}{1}\left(\binom{13k}{3}-\binom{12}{1}\binom{k}{1}^3\right)}
{\binom{52k}{3}}
}
$$
Explanation:

- Choose the suit: $\binom{4}{1}$ choices.

  Choose $3$ cards from that suit: $\binom{13k}{3}$ choices.

  Subtract the count for the straights:  $\binom{12}{1}\binom{k}{1}^3$ choices.

Comment: royal flush        COMBIN(4,1)
straight flush COMBIN(12,1)*COMBIN(4,1) - COMBIN(4,1)
straight         COMBIN(12,1) * (4 ^ 3  -  4)
flush         COMBIN(4,1)*(COMBIN(13,3) - 12)                                                 I calculated the 3-card, single deck combinations for other ranks are shown above.  But when I applied an 8 deck factor to the single deck equations the results doesn't look right.  Are my equations correct for single-deck, and what modifications are needed for 8-deck?